# Объясните пожалуйста как работает этот код. Совсем запутался

Tags: javascript

```js
const arr = [23, 44, 86, 96, 12, 33, 21]; 
        
for(let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {
      let x = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = x;
    }
  }
}

const min = arr[0];
const max = arr[arr.length - 1];

console.log(max, min,'Max/Min')
```

Comment: А что именно вам не ясно?

Comment: Это сортировка пузырьком. Вы читали о такой?

Comment: p.s. если надо найти максимальный и минимальный, то можно просто: `Math.max(...arr); Math.min(...arr);`

Comment: да, но нужно именно циклом сделать